# if statements to evaluate multiple file dates

Tags: c#

I am new to C# (less than a week), I have the following code that deletes a file on a volume. It is a back up file for an SQL database. And it keeps growing so periodically I have to rename the file and then delete it after a new file is backed up. I need to evaluate if the backup ran and then it is okay to delete the file.

```
    using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //
        // Delete a file found on the D:\ volume.
        // If the file is not found (File doesn't exist),
        // then you will get an exception.
        //
        try
        {
            File.Delete(@"\\Fabtrol-2\Program Files (x86)\FabTrolBackUp\FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK"); // Try to delete
            Console.WriteLine("Deleted"); // Success
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex); // Write error
        }
    }
}
```

This is the logic. If I'm asking too much let me know:

- If todays date  is = Monday and file  FT_FabTrol_Sun_Full.BAK ‘s  date  is less than 2     days old then it is okay to delete the file named FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK
- Else If todays date  is = Tuesday and file  FT_FabTrol_Mon_Full.BAK ‘s  date  is less than 2 days old then it is okay to delete the file  named FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK
- Else If todays date  is = Wednesday and file  FT_FabTrol_Tues_Full.BAK ‘s  date  is less than 2 days old then it is okay to delete the file named FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK
- Else If todays date  is = Thursday and file  FT_FabTrol_Wed_Full.BAK ‘s  date  is less than 2 days old then it is okay to delete the file  named FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK
- Else If todays date  is = Friday and file  FT_FabTrol_Thurs_Full.BAK ‘s  date  is less then 2 days old then it is okay to delete the file  named FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK
- Else If todays date  is = Saturday and file  FT_FabTrol_Fri_Full.BAK ‘s  date  is less than 2 days old then it is okay to delete the file  named FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK
- Else If todays date  is = Sunday and file  FT_FabTrol_Sat_Full.BAK ‘s  date  is less than 2 days old then it is okay to delete the file named FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK

Comment: The FileInfo class can help you get information about create/modify dates. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx

Comment: Perhaps you want to delete files that are older than two days and keep the more recent ones?

Comment: You can skip all those `ifs`. If file is not older than 2 days, delete it. Is that correct?

Comment: No, two conditions have to be met. 1)If todays date is = Sunday 2)and file FT_FabTrol_Sat_Full.BAK ‘s date is less than 2 days old, then it is okay to delete the file named FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK

Comment: I posted an answer that does both things.

Comment: @MichaelTerrian I updated my answer to fit your requirements (I think). Just fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code 1st checks if the file based on the day is less than 2 days old, then if it is it deletes the file FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK.

```
                string dir = @"\\Fabtrol-2\Program Files (x86)\FabTrolBackUp\";
                string fileName = dir;
                switch (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek)
                {
                    case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                        fileName += "FT_FabTrol_Sun_Full.BAK";
                        break;
                    case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                        fileName += "FT_FabTrol_Mon_Full.BAK";
                        break;
                    case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                        fileName += "FT_FabTrol_Tues_Full.BAK";
                        break;
                    case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                        fileName += "FT_FabTrol_Wed_Full.BAK";
                        break;
                    case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                        fileName += "FT_FabTrol_Thurs_Full.BAK";
                        break;
                    case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                        fileName += "FT_FabTrol_Fri_Full.BAK";
                        break;
                    case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                        fileName += "FT_FabTrol_Sat_Full.BAK";
                        break;
                }

                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(fileName);
                if (fi.Exists && DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) > fi.LastWriteTime.Date)
                {
                    (new FileInfo(dir + "FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK")).Delete();
                    Console.WriteLine("Deleted");
                }
```

Comment: It is in C# what he wrote was in words.  I understood the question to be asking how to write his if statement into c#.  I don't think the question was about how to test if it is 2 days old.

Comment: Nick tried it but get error Method name expected on this line (new FileInfo(dir + "FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK")()).Delete();

Comment: @MichaelTerrian I fixed it by removing the extra () in that line

Comment: When debuging I get the error Error "Use of unassigned local variable 'fileName' "

Comment: I can getpast the error if I add this to string filename = Path.GetFileName(@"\\Fabtrol-2\Program Files (x86)\FabTrolBackUp\");

Comment: @MichaelTerrian Oh sorry you have to change the line; string filename = dir;

Comment: Nick that did the trick. I had to do a little more tweaking but it works the way I need it to. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify that logic greatly with: -

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(@"\\Fabtrol-2\Program Files (x86)\FabTrolBackUp\FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK");
if(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2) > info.LastWriteTime.Date)
{
    //Delete
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is iterate over all the files in your folder and delete the ones that are older than two days, right (that seems to be what your giant conditional statement comes down to)?

So, use the following line to get all the files in the folder:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(<folder name>);
```

Then, in a loop, iterate over all the file names in `files` and check, whether they are old enough.

To get the timestamp of the file, use `FileInfo` and `LastWriteTime` like this:

```
if(DateTime.Today - someFileInfoObject.LastWriteTime.Date > new TimeSpan(2,0,0,0))
{
    File.Delete(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally for one weeks experience I would say you've jumped into the deep end.

I'm not going to provide code, rather direct you to improve your learning, this is referred to [psuedo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode)

1. Look into [streamwriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx)/reader and filewriter and fileinfo.
2. From this you can then read files, delete/rename/whatever you want really.
3. You then need to try and understand *how could I validate what I'm doing*.
   Unfortunately for a beginner this is harder than you may think, possibly harder than the first two points for some people. Think from simple onwards, we developers usually over complicate things. This part is actually rather easy so long your file stuff is correct!

You may want to look into unit testing as this may help your validation.

Answer (score 0):

Building on what @Gray commented, the FileInfo object will also let you know if it `.Exists` or not, alleviating the need to depend on the try/catch to know if a file is still there.

Consider the following:

```
static void Main()
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"\\path\\to\\file.bak");

    if(fi.Exists)
    {
        try
        {
            //because we can still get errors based on permissions etc.
            fi.Delete(); 
            Console.WriteLine("Deleted"); // Success
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex); // Write error
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
 string backupFile = @"\\Fabtrol-2\Program Files (x86)\FabTrolBackUp\FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK";
 FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(backupFile);
 DateTime fileCreatedDate = File.GetCreationTime(backupFile);
 DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
 if (today.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Monday && fileCreatedDate > today.AddDays(-2))
     {
        fi.Delete();
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer to meet your requirements. Kinda weird, but I was bored. May be helpful if just to read.

```
//2 days
TimeSpan daysToKeep = new TimeSpan(2,0,0,0);

//The folder where the files are kept
DirectoryInfo backupFolder = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\Fabtrol-2\Program Files (x86)\FabTrolBackUp\");
//the Appendold.BAK file
FileInfo backupLog = new FileInfo(backupFolder.FullName + @"\FT_Trans_Log_Appendedold.BAK");

//the base name for the log files
string logName = "FT_FabTrol_{0}_Full.BAK";
//an array for the days of week that are part of the logname
string[] days = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat" };
//get yesterday's log file name
string yesterdayLog = String.Format(logName, days[(int)DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).DayOfWeek]);
//create file info
FileInfo logFile = new FileInfo(backupFolder.FullName + yesterdayLog);

//if the file exists, and it is less than 2 days old
try
{
    if (logFile.Exists && (DateTime.Today - logFile.LastWriteTime < daysToKeep))
    {
        backupLog.Delete();
        Console.WriteLine("success");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("log file either did not exist or is not ready to delete");
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```